# Running suggested command doesn't fix NPM Vulnerability

Tags: node.js, npm, fsevents, npm-audit

After each installation of a new NPM module in my project I get the following error :

```
[!] 40 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 5840 (0 dev, 299 optional)
    Severity: 8 Low | 24 Moderate | 8 High
```

So then I run `npm audit` and I get the details for each of the 40 vulnerabilities such as :

```
# Run  npm install npm@6.0.1  to resolve 22 vulnerabilities
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Prototype pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ hoek                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > request > hawk >  │
│               │ boom > hoek                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

or this :

```
# Run  npm update fsevents --depth 2  to resolve 3 vulnerabilities
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ chokidar                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ chokidar > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > tar-pack > debug        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So I run `npm install npm@6.0.1` (even though I already had 6.0.1) then `npm update fsevents --depth 2` But after that I re-run `npm audit` and nothing has changed, I still have the same 40 vulnerabilities and some of them are really scary. What should I do ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `fsevents`, I've solved other vulnerabilities running the recommended commands but it doesn't seem to work for this package.

Comment: @davidivad I'm experiencing the exact same thing with `fsevents` and a couple of other packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me on MacOS:

- Update NPM to the new 6.1.0. It introduces a 'npm audit fix' command, [more info here](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases).
- Run 'npm audit fix'.

When you run 'npm audit' again, the only vulnerabilities left should be "Manual Review" issues.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in npm 6.0.1 related to handling of optional dependencies: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20577

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

> ```
> Do the npm audit suggestions that aren't npm updates
> Delete package-lock.json
> Delete the node_modules folder
> Run npm install again
> ```

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20684

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20675.
One `fsevents` issue may do with the fact that

> `fsevents` can't be installed on windows, so you will have to update it on a macOS machine.

That's a bit strange, since looking at exhnozoaa's solution, as of this date seems to imply otherwise:

> I was able to work around this on Windows with the following steps.
>
> 1. Open `package-lock.json` in an editor.
> 2. Search for `"fsevents"`. Find the one that is an object directly under `"dependencies"`.
> 3. Delete `"fsevents"` (the key and the whole object).
> 4. From the terminal, run `npm install`.
>
> This should regenerate that section with the latest version that is compatible with the other packages. I don't really think this is a good way to fix it, but it is one that worked for me.