# How to fix npm vulnerabilities manually?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

When I run `npm install` it says `` found 33 vulnerabilities (2 low, 31 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details ``.

However, `npm audit fix` outputs `up to date in 11s
fixed 0 of 33 vulnerabilities in 24653 scanned packages
  33 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated`

Does that `review` mean it is not supposed to be fixed by user?

When I run `npm audit` it gives me list of tables, similar to this:

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ browser-sync [dev]                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ browser-sync > easy-extender > lodash                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

In this example remediation section of linked page says `Update to version 4.17.5 or later.`. However, in `/node_modules/browser-sync/package.json` there are lines:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "lodash-cli": "4.17.5",
}
```

and no more lodash dependencies. So it should already be v4.17.5. I also checked `/node_modules/lodash/lodash.json` which has `var VERSION = '4.17.10';` line. In `/node_modules/lodash/package.json` there are these lines:

```
  "_from": "lodash@^4.17.4",
  "_id": "lodash@4.17.10",
```

I believe that version shown in "_id", not in "_from", so versions are correct but vulnerability still appear in audit list.

I'm still new in node.js and those messages confuses me a lot. Is there any way to fix it manually or get rid of those messages, I can't do anything with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a vulnerable npm package in my package-lock.json that isn't listed in the package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328324/how-do-i-fix-a-vulnerable-npm-package-in-my-package-lock-json-that-isnt-listed)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`lodash-cli` in `devDependencies` doesn't affect how `browser-sync` works in your project, `devDependencies` are ignored when a package is installed as a dependency.

What `audit` report says is that it's `easy-extender` that has `lodash` dependency:

```
browser-sync > easy-extender > lodash
```

It [depends on Lodash 3](https://github.com/shakyShane/easy-extender/blob/master/package.json#L32), while the problem was fixed in Lodash 4. The problem could be fixed by forking `easy-extender`, updating it and installing it instead of the package from NPM public registry. But there is no real problem with this dependency.

`audit` report importance should be evaluated manually. Even if nested dependency has security risk, this doesn't mean that a feature that introduces this risk was used. This also doesn't mean that even if it's used, it introduces real risk due to how it's used.

`browser-sync` is development tool that isn't used in production, there are not so many scenarios where its vulnerabilities could be exploited. And *Prototype Pollution* isn't a vulnerability at all, just a notice that a package doesn't follow good practices, it can be ignored.

Generally, this is the way to fix reported vulnerabilities:

- Do a sanity check
- In case it's a real problem, check the repository of vulnerable package for existing issues *and* PRs
- In case there's none, submit an issue
- Fork a repository or use use existing PR as [git dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) until it's fixed in NPM release
- In case of nested dependencies, do this at several levels of nesting

Most times it's expected that you won't advance beyond a sanity check, and the only problem is that a "vulnerability" clutters audit report and conceals real vulnerabilities.

[`patch-package`](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) can help to patch nested dependencies in-place but this won't affect the report.

It's possible to force specific dependency version in nested dependency in Yarn 1 and 2 with [`resolutions` field](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/), this will affect audit report. It may be possible to do this [natively in NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416312/npm-equivalent-of-yarn-resolutions) in future. Currently the alternative in NPM is third-party [`npm-force-resolutions`](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions) utility that gives less control, currently it forces a resolution for [all dependencies, not a specific one](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/32).

**Notice that by forcing a dependency to use nested dependencies it wasn't designed to work with, it can become broken at any moment. This especially applies to `npm-force-resolutions`, which is a blunt tool and can affect many nested dependencies at once.**

Comment: I didn't pay attention to Path section, and it really uses lodash v3.10.1, thanks. But browser-sync is just example, last one of list. So, I can ignore 2 low vulnerabilities, but can I ignore 31 moderate ones? I suppose I shouldn't modify anything in `node_modules`, so is forking and fixing is only way to get rid of them? And as new user I haven't capability to do that? Should I issue package developers about them?

Comment: *but can I ignore 31 moderate ones?* - this is what 'sanity check' is about, use your judgement. The more attention you pay to what these reports actually say, the better developer you can become, security-wise. *Should I issue package developers about them?* - you likely should (at least to shut `audit` up), the answer answers that. People lived without `npm audit` somehow. Chances that they cause real security problems to the app are very low, yet without knowing what they are and how they are used in your app, I cannot guarantee that.

Comment: Thanks! Took time to write comment, so didn't see edited part before commenting.

Answer (score 19):

If you are absolutely certain you'd like to skip the audit, you can do so by appending  --no-audit

```
 npm install --no-audit
```

[Source: Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities#turning-off-npm-audit-on-package-installation)

Cases may be

- false positives
- vulnerabilities that have no effect in your particular environment
- vulnerabilities that are present in parts of code you make no use of

[False positives further reading](https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/the-issue-with-vuln-scanners/)

[Wrong contexts further reading](https://www.theregister.com/2021/07/09/npm_audit_security/)

**Update 2022**

Alternatively you could use [Better NPM audit](https://github.com/jeemok/better-npm-audit) to micro-manage the audit

Answer (score 10):

'npm audit fix' will increment the version of dependency in package.json which might lead to breaking of code.
So better way is to open package-lock.json and updated the dependency/subdependency versions to required version. Maintain the package-lock.json in repository.

Sometimes vulnerabilities are from dev packages, In that case ignore those vulnerabilities as those are not getting picked up in the production.

Comment: What about adding/updating dev packages  from the package.json file itself? Any inconvenient with this approach? https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Comment: What is the point of just updating package-lock and not updating package.json? How does that fix anything?

Answer (score 7):

use this

> npm audit fix --force --production

may be solve your problem

Comment: it will forcefully install package versions with breaking changes

Answer (score 1):

You can you use force also like `npm audit fix --force`.

Comment: However this will include breaking changes

Comment: Also not always working. For example I get: "added 555 packages from 172 contributors, removed 350 packages and updated 1500 packages in 52.021s
fixed 0 of 22 vulnerabilities in 2057 scanned packages
  22 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated"

Answer (score 0):

True vulnerabilities (and exposures) in security sense have their allotted unique CVE and/or GHSA IDs. JavaScript packages can now be scanned for such vulnerabilities with several wide-coverage security scanning tools such as Anchore Grype, Trivy or Snyk, which can point you to the path of the problematic `package.json` file and show you the version of the installed package as well as the CVE/GHSA ID. These scanners can be also applied to perform automated scans of entire Docker containers before their deployment is allowed (as part of e.g. Jenkins pipelines).

Manual fixing of a CVE in a JS package (if `npm audit fix` cannot do it automatically) consists of either upgrading e.g. with `npm i <package>@<patch_version>` if a security patch already exists (which can be verified with `npm outdated <package>`), potentially several times (at all levels of nesting), or by whitelisting the CVE number and package combination before such patch becomes available (of if it is in the "won't fix" category). Occasionally `node` itself has to be upgraded if the `node` binary is the affected file - you can do it using `nvm install <major_ver> && nvm alias default <major_ver>`.

Answer (score -8):

I tried this and it worked for me, run the following commands:

```
> npm audit fix    
> npm set audit false
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: more info needed

Comment: Turning off audit does not fix vulnerabilities - you stopped seeing vulnerabilities because you turned audit off. The question is about fixing them manually, not hiding them.