# Why I can't update npm package dependancy?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I've done npm audit and it showed me that I have one High vulnerability. That's the information that it gave to me:

```
┌───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                        │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                             │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                         │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ node-sass-chokidar                              │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ node-sass-chokidar > node-sass > node-gyp > tar │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                |
└───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I looked at my package-lock.json for node-gyp package and I found that tar package still has version 2.0.0 however I need 4.4.8:

```
"node-gyp": {
    "version": "3.8.0",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp/-/node-gyp-3.8.0.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-3g8lYefrRRzvGeSowdJKAKyks8oUpLEd/DyPV4eMhVlhJ0aNaZqIrNUIPuEWWTAoPqyFkfGrM67MC69baqn6vA==",
    "requires": {
        "fstream": "^1.0.0",
        "glob": "^7.0.3",
        "graceful-fs": "^4.1.2",
        "mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
        "nopt": "2 || 3",
        "npmlog": "0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4",
        "osenv": "0",
        "request": "^2.87.0",
        "rimraf": "2",
        "semver": "~5.3.0",
        "tar": "^2.0.0",
        "which": "1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "nopt": {
            "version": "3.0.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-3.0.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-xkZdvwirzU2zWTF/eaxopkayj/k=",
            "requires": {
                "abbrev": "1"
            }
        },
        "semver": {
            "version": "5.3.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-5.3.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-myzl094C0XxgEq0yaqa00M9U+U8="
        },
        "tar": {
            "version": "2.2.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-jk0qJWwOIYXGsYrWlK7JaLg8sdE=",
            "requires": {
                "block-stream": "*",
                "fstream": "^1.0.2",
                "inherits": "2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I searched for the same problem so I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43453240/5184474). Then I did

```
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules/
npm i -g npm npm-check-updates
ncu -g
ncu -u
npm i
```

but the version for tar package still remains the same. I also tried updating it directly with `npm install tar@4.4.8` but it just put tar in my package.json. I also tried npm update and npm outdated. Everything looks up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-gyp@3.8.0` depends on `"tar@^2.0.0`, updating `tar` to 4.4.8 won't affect `node-gyp`.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380528/3731501), vulnerability reports should pass a sanity check and be taken with a grain of salt. If there's nested package that has a vulnerability, all packages that depend on it should be updated, this may be complicated. On the other hand, if vulnerable package is used in a way that cannot cause security problems, it's not a vulnerability.

`node-sass-chokidar` is development package, it's unlikely that `tar` nested dependency can cause security problems for the project. Reported 'vulnerability' cannot be easily fixed. Ignore the report. In case there's no issue yet (actually, [there is](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2625)), open it in `node-sass` and `node-sass-chokidar` repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its called package-lock.json for a reason, that version will always remain the same.

if you want to update your packages you will need to remove that file, or rename it to package.json then perform your update.