# some vulnerabilities are shown in npm install command

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, axios

I'm new to JAVASCRIPT and got this report when invoking **'npm audit command'** after seeing vulnerabilities in npm install command.

what I've done is just adding functionality to my server/client project, added HTTP request(DELETE, POST) in Axios and their respective HTTP response on express.

**EDIT** - I've tried using 'npm audit fix' but it says - "10 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated"

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/add > @evocateur/pacote >                     │
│               │ @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen >          │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/create > @evocateur/pacote >                  │
│               │ @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen >          │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/publish > @evocateur/pacote >                 │
│               │ @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen >          │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/publish > @evocateur/libnpmaccess >           │
│               │ @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen >          │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/publish > @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch >     │
│               │ make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/publish > @lerna/npm-dist-tag >               │
│               │ @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen >          │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/publish > @lerna/npm-publish >                │
│               │ @evocateur/libnpmpublish > @evocateur/npm-registry-fetch >   │
│               │ make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/add > @evocateur/pacote > make-fetch-happen > │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/create > @evocateur/pacote >                  │
│               │ make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ lerna [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ lerna > @lerna/publish > @evocateur/pacote >                 │
│               │ make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 10 high severity vulnerabilities in 43519 scanned packages
  10 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

seem like they are all quite related to one another but I don't quite understand what is happening here.

Comment: Generally, you need to just update your code to use the latest version of whatever had the vulnerability. Judging by that audit, it seems like it really wants you to use a version of `https-proxy-agent` at or above `3.0.0`.  Also please keep in mind that questions should contain a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix npm vulnerabilities manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377148/how-to-fix-npm-vulnerabilities-manually)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the result of an `npm audit` command.

You can automatically install compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies by running `npm audit fix`.

[NPM Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)

Comment: I've edited, I get the response to Manuel reviewing it.