# NPM says 1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated

Tags: reactjs, security, npm, dependencies

When I created a new project using React.js I found 1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated:

[image: CMD console with vulnerability]

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377148/how-to-fix-npm-vulnerabilities-manually

Answer (score 0):

try running below command

```
npm audit fix
```

Comment: I have already used this command after that it is showing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbtXf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

try npm audit to review the  vulnerabilities

> npm audit

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm audit` to get the details. It will give you link where you can look for some solution. This is how I solved an error similar to yours.