# fixed 0 of 86 vulnerabilities in 1929 scanned packages 86 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

Tags: npm

I create a new react project and it says

```
found 86 vulnerabilities (82 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

after I run "npm audit fix" it says

```
fixed 0 of 86 vulnerabilities in 1929 scanned packages
  86 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

Can somebody help me to fix those vulnerabilities ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix npm vulnerabilities manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377148/how-to-fix-npm-vulnerabilities-manually)

Comment: No it doesn't answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check if you are using the latest version of all your dependencies:

```
npm outdated
```

Comment: I run "npm outdated" and I saw that I don't have latest version of all dependencies. How can I update them ?

Comment: Please check the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version