# Not able to install react-router-dom

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

[image] Why `react-router-dom` is not installing in my vs-code and how to fix it.

It shows 6 high vulnerabilities, I also run `npm audit fix --force` and `npm audit` but nothing happened.
How to remove these vulnerabilities?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code and errors should not be presented as images.

Comment: `react-router-dom` did install successfully, albeit with vulnerabilities. Are you certain `npm audit fix --force` didn't work? Try running it without `--force` to better understand the vulnerabilities and determine how best to resolve them. 

Running it with `--force` will tell `npm` to resolve them by whatever means it deems necessary which may not always be the desired results.

Comment: It looks like it _did_ install. What makes you think it didn't?

Comment: It installed from what I can tell. You can ignore the audit warnings for the post part. Use caution with the `--force` flag as this will bump major versions of your dependencies and potentially cause more issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just tried it, react-router-dom installs and also works on your part as I can see.

Try to fix the vulnerabilities by doing these steps:

```bash
npm outdated // run to check outdated npm packages

npx npm-check-updates -u // run to check updates outdated npm packages

npm install // run to update npm packages
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70920497/12772716