How to fix vulnerabilities in npm?
When installing the packages always shows vulnerabilities.

I'm new to using React and I'm encountering some npm-related issues. Could you please provide clear instructions on how to fix them? I'm not very familiar with npm, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The output provides some instructions for how to address vulnerabilities. What have you tried?

You probably shouldn't. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377148/how-to-fix-npm-vulnerabilities-manually

I see that the output provides some instructions for addressing vulnerabilities. I'm new to this, and I'm not sure which steps to take.  Should I start with 'npm fund', then 'npm audit fix', and finally 'npm audit fix --force'? Thank you for your help!

If there are vulnerabilities, will they affect the functioning of my application? Should I be concerned about them affecting the running process?

npm fund, no, this is packages "advertising" that they would like your donation as a show of support. Use npm audit fix to fix what is fixable. Don't use the --force flag as this will update everything, including newer versions with possibly/likely breaking changes. I think most devs have gone "blind" to these warnings, so long as the package successfully installs you're probably good to go.

@NSSWeerasinghe It's very rarely the case for front-end projects, but when they are, they are. See the linked question. You're the one who's responsible for distinguishing the real vulnerabilities and the ones which can't make the app vulnerable even in theory, this includes taking the ways they are used in your project into account.

First, you should try the recommended actions by the output. Whenever the console output tells you to do something, you should do it.
Try:
npm audit fix
and if that doesn't work, try
npm audit fix --force
But remember, Bootstrap and React are large packages with many dependencies. Unless you are working for a large company that cares about data security, for your project, it should be okay if all components work as intended.
If you do care about the vulnerabilities, refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities for more information on fixing vulnerabilities
