Running npm update doesn't?
I ran npm outdated --depth=3. Got the report with about 65 outdated packages, so I ran npm update.
Results:
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.4: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.4: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

added 40 packages, removed 317 packages, changed 348 packages, and audited 1763 packages in 4m

After running the update, ran npm outdated --depth=3 again. The list was exactly the same as before.
Why would it show outdated packages after running an update?

It's unknown what's your case, what the deps were before and after the update. But generally it doesn't make sense to specify "depth" and expect that all of them will be updated, as these are nested deps with version restrictions. It's the same problem as with audit, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/51377148 , and the answer would be the same, don't force this without a reason, you'll just cause yourself inconvenience and break things. If the problem persists with depth=0 then that's another case

As mentioned in following article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-npm-dependencies/ , npm update doesn't update to a major breaking-changes version. I don't know if it's your case, but it is something that you could check
