Need to remove or update vulnerable dependencies in a NodeJS API
In a NodeJS API, I have a dependency swagger-express-mw-updated-dependencies which has vulnerabilities in a sonarqube scan. This package only has one version 0.7.0 in npm. It is just a wrapper around swagger-express-mw wht re someone updated a few dependencies. So then I checked swagger-express-mw thinking that maybe someone had updated it and it also has no updates after 0.7.0.
swagger-express-mw is simply a wrapper around swagger-node-runner. I checked that one and it actually has versions up to 0.7.3, but even in 0.7.3 it has the same vulnerabilities as the other ones.
I wanted to remove this swagger package altogether, thinking it was just documenting the API with swagger, but apparently this package actually validates input/output, generates responses so you don't have to write code.
Actually I did have a branch where I removed the package, but some of the endpoints no longer worked correctly so I scrapped it.
I googled how to migrate away from this package and the Internet is suggesting express-openapi. But to upgrade to that I will actually have to write code where I wire up dependencies and use a folder structure for my routes, whereas swagger-express-mw-updated-dependencies simply has a controllers folder and everything is wired up via the yaml file.
This seems like a bad option because this code base is ~20k lines of code with roughly  200 api endpoints so it's practically a re-write. Almost everything write now happens in a 3500 line yaml file.
The other option was to just use package overrides or npm force resolutions, but even that seems like a deadend.
I added a screenshot where you can see the package vulnerabilities:

It seems some of these packages have no vulnerability fixes at all and then others I would have to upgrade to a major version with breaking changes.
Can anyone give me advice on this one? I need to get rid of the vulnerabilities, but this app is in production and I can't break anything either.
I've fixed dozens of vulnerabilities recently, with no issues, but this one is leaving me scratching my head.
Tried removing package swagger-express-mw-updated-dependencies from my node project to get rid of vulnerabilities, but it broke some of my API endpoints.
UPDATE
Here is a list of the actual vulnerabilities in Sonarqube:
busboy:0.2.14 | Reference: CVE-2022-24434 | CVSS Score: 7.5 | Category: CWE-noinfo | This affects all versions of package dicer. A malicious attacker can send a modified form to server, and crash the nodejs service. An attacker could sent the payload again and again so that the service continuously crashes. Sonatype's research suggests that this CVE's details differ from those defined at NVD. See https://ossindex.sonatype.org/vulnerability/CVE-2022-24434 for details
dicer:0.2.5 | Reference: GHSA-wm7h-9275-46v2 | CVSS Score: 7.5 | Category: CWE-248 | This affects all versions of the package dicer. A malicious attacker can send a modified form to the server and crash the Node.js service. A complete denial of service can be achieved by sending the malicious form in a loop.
dicer:0.2.5 | Reference: CVE-2022-24434 | CVSS Score: 7.5 | Category: NVD-CWE-noinfo | This affects all versions of package dicer. A malicious attacker can send a modified form to server, and crash the nodejs service. An attacker could sent the payload again and again so that the service continuously crashes.
validator:10.11.0 | Reference: CVE-2021-3765 | CVSS Score: 7.5 | Category: CWE-1333 | validator.js is vulnerable to Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity
async:1.5.2 | Reference: CVE-2021-43138 | CVSS Score: 7.8 | Category: CWE-1321 | In Async before 2.6.4 and 3.x before 3.2.2, a malicious user can obtain privileges via the mapValues() method, aka lib/internal/iterator.js createObjectIterator prototype pollution.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380528/3731501 . You potentially need to ignore this as they probably aren't real "vulnerabilities". And you certainly need to think if you need this before doing anything. The problem with your question is that you didn't provide details on those "vulnerabilities"

I added the vulnerabilities

Still needs to be verified, but it could be a real security problem due to how the package works. It's totally expected that this has been already addressed by other devs in issues and existing forks in swagger-node-runner and swagger-express repos. The latest active ones I see here https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-node-runner/forks do this, e.g. https://github.com/autodesk-forks/swagger-express
