# How to fix vulnerability in npm dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-request

I got 18 vulnerabilities by giving  `npm audit` , then i went for the one which is labeled as high.

here is its detail,

```
  High            Denial-of-Service Memory Exhaustion                           

  Package         qs                                                            

  Patched in      >= 1.x                                                        

  Dependency of   google-search-scraper                                         

  Path            google-search-scraper > request > qs                          

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/29
```

it seems like we need to update request package , so by `>npm i request` 
i have installed it.

now what next, the audit command is giving same results again

please help ,

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
Moderate        Prototype pollution                                           

  Package         hoek                                                          

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3                                   

  Dependency of   botkit                                                        

  Path            botkit > botbuilder > jsonwebtoken > joi > hoek               

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566
```

Comment: Did you try using `npm audit fix`?

Comment: This is related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dgmeTy7X3I If I remember correctly, the speaker mentions the very `qs` vulnerability of interest, although doesn't tell how to fix it

Comment: yes , but it didn't work . Actually we have 18 different vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

As the report says, `qs` vulnerability has been fixed in 1.x. It's not a problem for latest `request` versions. `google-search-scraper` has `request@~2.33.0` dependency that depends on `qs@~0.6.0`. Regardless of which `request` version is installed in the project, `google-search-scraper` will continue to use 2.33.x version that contains vulnerability.

`google-search-scraper` should be forked and used instead of original package, `request` dependency version should be updated in a fork, e.g. to `request@^2.33.0`. Additionally, an issue can be opened in package repository and supplemented with a PR.

Comment: thanks for reply, okay so its not a version problem , then what is the problem ,

Comment: i have already forked and cloned the project (which is using the google search scraper) , so now how should i go about it .

Comment: The problem is that `google-search-scraper` is messed up and is hard-coded to use vulnerable `request` version. Whether it's your own project or forked one is irrelevant in this context. You need to fork specifically `google-search-scraper` and use it instead of official one.

Comment: I have edited the question with one more vulnerability , this must be a version problem , i have installed it by > npm i hoek , but still it is not working . please help , i have never worked on these stuff before

Comment: This is not a vulnerability. Do sanity check when evaluating `npm audit` reports. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852121/3731501 . Any way, feel free to open issues in packages that cause audit problems, as long as latest package version imposes them.

Comment: how to do sanity check while doing npm audit , i didn't know about it , thanks for telling

Comment: Just check what reported 'vulnerability' actually is, where it comes from and whether it's capable to affect your app at all - directly or through nested dependencies. audit is a blunt tool that creates a lot of noise that doesn't need to be fixed most times, especially the issues labeled with 'moderate' or lower.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that has worked for me is by initially creating JSON file which will be the manifest. Before installing the npm package start with the following`npm init -y`
that way you agree to all the details that will be added by the JSON file, you can edit them afterwards.

Then proceed with `npm install <package name>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).